# 2DLights - Universal Render Pipeline - Lightweight RP

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm working with Unity 2019.4.11f1, "Universal Render Pipeline" with "Lightweight RP" (package version 7.5.1).
I defined a "2D Renderer Data" to work with 2D Lights.
In my game I have four 2D lights:

- Two "Point" 2DLights (each point light has 3 target sorting layers)
- Two "Global" 2DLights. One of them with 3 target sorting layers (lights up my whole game except characters) and the other with 1 sorting layer (Illuminates only my characters).

I'm developing a 2D mobile game for kids and using 2D lights to decorate.
Only ONE "Point" 2DLight is turned on at the same time.
The "Global" light, which illuminates my characters, is always turned on.
The "Global" light, which illuminates my whole game (except characters), is ON only when the point light is OFF.

At certain times in my game, I turn on/off "Point" lights and "Global" light with the above restriction already described.

Everything works great until I use shadows on my characters.
When I use shadows, the frame rate is dropped right down to about 10 fps otherwise it's about 27.

My 2D game is pretty simple. My characters are round sprites (like a coin), so shadows are ridiculously simple.
To gain in performance, I set "Renderer Texture Scale" to 0.4 (insted of default value 1) in the object 2D Renderer Data.
While the performance has greatly improved after that, it is still low.

Each character (above 10 on screen, moving around) has a "Shadow Caster 2D (Experimental)" component and checkbox "Cast shadows" selected.

What else can I do to improve performance? I've done a lot of research and can't figure out what else I can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can

1. Decrease the size of your sprites (or compression)
2. Make static gameobjects whichs are non have movement
3. Check your renderer graphics detail
4. You can make manual occlusion to your game (you can enable and disable gameobject in the scene)
5. You can use OnBecameVisible() function.

I am using these to optimize my urp game.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. I did a lot of optimizations including some of the ones you already mentioned. The bottleneck is when the shadows are activated because if not, my game works at (near) 30fps (the maximum that my mobile reaches).
I understand that the problem is not inefficiency in my game but something in the "Lightweight RP" package that when activating shadows degrades the whole game.
Could you please describe in more detail points 3 and 4?

Comment: You can configure your urp renderer settings, it may provide some fps boost. . (You can see in editor > quality > renderer (in this case 2d renderer))  (Sorry about list item, it's stackoverflow list item :( )

Comment: Yes I know, but it's very hard to know what to change.

Comment: You can decrease shadow resolution for example. Also if you using post-processing you may want to change your effects because some of the effects can strain the system.

Comment: Yes, I set "Renderer Texture Scale" to 0.4 to gain in performance. But the game continues to slow down as time goes by. It's as if the shadows caused memory leaks.I'm not using post-processing yet.